# use Search View in a fragment's action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, searchview

I want use search view in a fragment's action bar , and my code in fragment is like

---

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {


    menu.clear();
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

menu_search

---

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.sinyuk.zhihu.Search.SearchResultActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="90"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

---

and my code in activity is:

---

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    ...
    return true;
}
```

---

menu_main

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
...
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="83"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

The problem is I can't get the search view , it turns out to be  a null object.
But the menu view in fragment is actually re-created, it seems the new Menu didn't pass to the

---

```
 MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
```

---

so please help me :P

Comment: Use the `app` namespace `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

Comment: Did you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in fragment `onCreate()`?

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by kris larson. 
You have to pass true to setHasOptionsMenu(); in the fragments' onCreate() like so

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

then you could set your onCreateOptionsMenu like so

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        sv=(SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Comment: i want to make a search view that have select mysql database record show in andorid application using fragment